# How To Edit PDF Report In Odoo 15

Tags: python, xml, pdf, odoo, odoo-15

i want to update pdf report to replace the customer address and name with customer email and phone.

i have inherited the sale_report_templates.xml located in addons/sale/report in odoo 15 source code

i create new xml file called sale_report_inherited.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
 <template id="sale_report_inherit_template" inherit_id="report_saleorder_document">
 <xpath expr="//div[@t-field='doc.partner_id']" position="replace">

 <div t-field="doc.partner_id"
 t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["email", "phone"], "no_marker": True}' />
 </xpath>
 </template>
</odoo>
```

i updated the manifest

```
data : [
         report/sale_report_inherited.xml',
       ]
```

my code looks good,
but when i tried to update the app i got this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
> r = d[key]   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 71, in wrapper
> return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 34, in **getitem**
> a = self.d[obj] KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData._xmlid_lookup at 0x7f9c9d49b250>,
> 'om_company.report_saleorder_document')
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 680, in _tag_root
> f(rec)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 658, in _tag_template
> return self._tag_record(record)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 567, in _tag_record
> f_val = self.id_get(f_ref)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 663, in id_get
> res = self.model_id_get(id_str, raise_if_not_found)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 669, in model_id_get
> return self.env['ir.model.data']._xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(id_str,
> raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)   File
> "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1943, in
> _xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
> return self._xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]   File "", line 2, in _xmlid_lookup   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line
> 90, in lookup
> value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1936, in
> _xmlid_lookup
> raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid) ValueError: External ID not found in the system:
> om_company.report_saleorder_document
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
> result = request.dispatch()   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 687, in dispatch
> result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
> return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
> return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 348, in checked_call
> result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 916, in **call**
> return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 535, in response_wrap
> response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1346, in call_button
> action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1334, in _call_kw
> return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 464, in call_kw
> result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 451, in _call_kw_multi
> result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)   File "", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade   File
> "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 74, in
> check_and_log
> return method(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 662, in
> button_immediate_upgrade
> return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 600, in
> _button_immediate_function
> registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line
> 87, in new
> odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 470,
> in load_modules
> processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 363, in load_marked_modules
> loaded, processed = load_module_graph(   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
> load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 69, in load_data
> tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 745, in
> convert_file
> convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 811, in convert_xml_import
> obj.parse(doc.getroot())   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 731, in parse
> self._tag_root(de)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 693, in _tag_root
> raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, somewhere inside\n%s' % ( Exception
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py",
> line 643, in _handle_exception
> return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
> raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing None:3, somewhere inside
>
> ```
>         <div t-field="doc.partner_id" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;,
> ```
>
> "fields": ["email", "phone"],
> "no_marker": True}"/>

if you notice what i did wrong,i'll be greatful for your help

Answer (score 0):

When the full xml id is not provided (`MODULE_NAME.TEMPLATE_ID`), Odoo will try to use [the current module](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/tools/convert.py#L669-L672) name as the `MODULE_NAME`

```py
def model_id_get(self, id_str, raise_if_not_found=True):
        if '.' not in id_str:
            id_str = '%s.%s' % (self.module, id_str)
        return self.env['ir.model.data']._xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(id_str, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
```

Use [sale.report_saleorder_document](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/fa58938b3e2477f0db22cc31d4f5e6b5024f478b/addons/sale_product_matrix/report/sale_report_templates.xml#L3) instead